# Anomalous results getting color components of some UIColors

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, uicolor, cgcolor

I'm trying to extract the rgb components of a `UIColor` in order to hand-build the pixels in a `CGBitmapContext`. The following sample code works fine for most of the `UIColor` constants but, confusingly, not all. To wit:

```
CGColorRef color = [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];
const float* rgba = CGColorGetComponents(color);

float r = rgba[0];
float g = rgba[1];
float b = rgba[2];
float a = rgba[3];

NSLog( @"r=%f g=%f b=%f a=%f", r, g, b, a);
```

The results for `[UIColor yellowColor]` above are
r=1.000000 g=1.000000 b=0.000000 a=1.000000,
as expected.

`[UIColor redColor]` gives
r=1.000000 g=0.000000 b=0.000000 a=1.000000,
again as expected. Similarly for `blueColor` and `greenColor`.

*However*, the results for `[UIColor blackColor]` and `[UIColor whiteColor]` seem completely anomalous, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong (if indeed I am).

To wit, `[UIColor blackColor]` gives
    r=0.000000 g=1.000000 b=0.000000 a=0.000000,
which is a tranparent green,

and `[UIColor whiteColor]` gives
    r=1.000000 g=1.000000 b=0.000000 a=0.000000,
which is a transparent yellow.

I'd appreciate it if somebody could either:

(1) explain what I'm doing wrong
(2) replicate my anomalous results and tell me it's not me, or
(3) hit me over the head with a big hammer so it stops hurting so much.

Howard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are assuming the color space is always RGBA, which is not the case.

Try this code:

```
CGColorRef color = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
const CGFloat* rgba = CGColorGetComponents(color);
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorGetColorSpace(color);
CGColorSpaceModel model = CGColorSpaceGetModel(space);
NSLog(@"%d", model);
```

And model will yield `kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I've been confused before by the frequent reference to `CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color)` before calling `CGColorGetComponents(color)`. Now I see why. By the way, isn't there a way of printing out the *name* of the model above, and not just its value?

Comment: The debugger will show you the name, I'm not sure you can print it, since it's a const definition of a number.

Answer (score 2):

I think the thing you're missing is that colors can be defined in different color spaces: you're assuming they're all RGBA.

For instance, [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/blackColor) state that `blackColor` "Returns a color object whose grayscale value is 0.0 and whose alpha value is 1.0". So I think only two components are valid for black, not four.